# Can't update app in store because of target api23 (no downgrade possible)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, google-play, metaio, android-api-levels

**long story short:**

- I have an app in the store, uploaded with target(!) api23
- Now I have to use the metaio SDK (Augmented reality) to implement a feature
- this SDK is not maintained anymore (company got bought & closed by apple)
- metaio SDK crashes when using a target api23

  - ...because of text relocations in the ffmpeg lib, in libavcodec.so, see also:
  - [libavcodec.so: has text relocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346402/libavcodec-so-has-text-relocations)
  - http://rg4.net/archives/1973.html
  - https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/issues/64

**Problem:**

- apps uploaded with target api23 once, can't be updated with lower target api
- metaio can't handle api23, due to a text relocations bug

**Idea so far:**

- replace the old libavcodec.so (arm & x86) by a newer version,
  but I can't find any compiled version...

*PS: sure it's dump to use a deprecated sdk and it has to be replaced sometime in the future, but for now I have to use it, as there's a huge content and backend part that is used in the project.*

*PPS: worst case idea is to upload the same app but with a different ID, api22 and AR features in the GooglePlay...and having two nearly identical apps... <_<*

Thanks a lot for every help! :)

Comment: As you mentioned, have you tried recompiling FFmpeg and dropping in the updated binaries with the disable-asm flag?

Answer (score 2):

### Short Term Solution

Wrap every call to the library with `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`. This will disable all functionality that relies on the library. You should probably notify the user of an API 23 device in this case.

### Long Term Solution

Find a replacement. If you have a no longer maintained dependency which is already incompatible with current versions, it will only get worse.

Comment: I already had the same thought =/ ... But in this case my users with 6.x can't use the AR features... and sure... replacing it in the long term is a must... =/

Answer (score -1):

You can publish the old version of your application with an updated version code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164218/3789575

Comment: even the first version of the app has api23, so I can't use an older version. Uploading a new APK always forces me to have a higher versionCode and at least the same target-api.

Comment: what do u want to tell me? Setting to target api23 lets the sdk crash, as said. Setting the target to api22 results in being unable to update the app...

Comment: I gave a link, which describes why it's impossible to downgrade targetSdkVersion.

Comment: I know the reasons, but unfortunately I need a solution in some way... maybe patching the .so files or sth...